# Changed fields in Opal Hotel Room Booking reservation form, got a 'required' error

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, validation, checkout

I'm not a PHP expert so some advice on how to do this would be very much appreciated! I'm using this plugin, [Opal Hotel Room Booking](https://wordpress.org/plugins/opal-hotel-room-booking/) with Wordpress.

The plugin goes through a series of steps during the booking process: Add date, Select Room, and then it goes to a Customer Details form (Name, country, etc.)

I did not want all the fields with the plugin, specifically Address, City State and Postcode; and managed to remove those fields by navigating to templates/checkout/customer-info.php and deleting them from the template file.

But I get the following errors:

"State is a required field.
City is a required field.
Postcode is a required field."

I've tried looking into the plugin files and searched their documentation to no avail. Can anyone please please help me with this? Or point me in the direction of which I should be looking? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is looking for a solution to this, here are the files to copy to your theme and edit:

```
wp-content/plugins/opal-hotel-room-booking/includes/class-opalhotel-checkout.php

wp-content/plugins/opal-hotel-room-booking/templates/checkout/customer-info.php

wp-content/plugins/opal-hotel-room-booking/templates/checkout/received/order-customer-details.php
```

and to plug your custom fields in emails:

```
wp-content/plugins/opal-hotel-room-booking/templates/emails/customer-details.php
```